# What will dapper do with a predicate?

Tags: c#, dapper

If I have a method that returns a `List of Dogs`, does `Dapper` convert the `Where` predicate into a `SQL` Where? or does it get all the dogs first and then filter the list?

```
public IList<Dog> GetDogsBy(Func<Dog, bool> predicate)
{
    return db.Query<Dog>("SELECT * FROM Dog",null).Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This one will definitely be executed by your app and not translated into SQL.

Comment: To confirm; that predicate is LINQ-to-Objects and is not processed by dapper. Dapper does not claim to be a full-weight ORM. There *are* some useful common predicate etc tools in some of the additional related dapper tools, however

Comment: How about you consider using the Dapper-Extensions (https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions)?

Answer (score 19):

It depends on what overload resolution does when resolving the `Where`.

If the result of the call to `Query` is a `List<Dog>` and you have a `using System.Linq;` directive, and the argument is a delegate, then the `Where` will resolve to the LINQ-to-objects version of `Where`. So the select query will run on the server, and then the `Where` will run on the client.

If the result of `Query` is `IQueryable<Dog>` and the argument is an `Expression` then overload resolution will choose the `Where` which combines with the existing query. When that query is executed, the `Where` runs on whatever side the query providers chooses to run it on, which is typically the server.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to see you got a downvote for an entirely correct answer that covered both possibilities. As it happens, dapper simply returns `IEnumerable<T>` and makes no attempt to process expression trees, so your first explanation applies. Whether that `IEnumerable<T>` happens to be a `List<T>` versus an incomplete open sequence sat over an ADO.NET reader depends on the optional `buffered` parameter.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks for the extra details!

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to SQL trnalsation, while an *expression tree* can be translated, a *compiled method* cannot. This is because once the method is compiled, it's a matter of reading IL to perform the translation, which is not exposed through the .NET API, whereas Expression Trees are explicitly designed to be navigated using metacode for the sake of translation.

Because you're passing in a `Func<...>` instead of an `Expression<Func<...>>`, you're passing that compiled method, and thus the code cannot get the expression tree, and thus the above code either will not work or will execute on your local machine.

If you were to replace the method signature with

```
public IList<Dog> GetDogsBy(Expression<Func<Dog, bool>> predicate)
```

Then it might be able to perform that translation, depending on the semantics of Dapper.